# Can I use import requests/mechanize to send form data to a Perl script from a text file at a set time interval?

Tags: python, forms, perl, post, intervals

I am attempting to complete a challenge in which I have to "social engineer" a web bot named Eliza. To my knowledge, when I issue the correct phrases to the form (a Perl script), I will be given the "password" and be allowed to pass to the next level. (I am sick of entering phrases manually...I've been at it for days!)

What I would like to do is use a dictionary file and post words and/or phrases to the form at a set interval.

The form I use to post my phrases looks like this:

```
<FORM ACTION="http://www.ca-zeb.com/zebulun/zebulun2/eliza.pl/1903" 
METHOD="POST" ENCTYPE="x-www-form-encoded" target="main_frame" name="MyForm"> 
<input type="text" NAME="input" size="35" maxlength="200">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Talk">
</FORM>
```

Is there a way to use import request or mechanize to post the dictionary file to this form, one line at a time, at a set interval?

I have the following code which will print the contents of a file at an interval of 2 seconds.

```
from time import sleep
with open('c:\dictionary.txt', 'r', 0) as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.strip()
        sleep(2)
```

Is there a way for me to integrate this code with import request/mechanize to achieve my goal?

I am very very new to Python. Any tips would be appreciated. Thank you for considering my question.

Comment: Why does this question have a Perl tag?

Comment: @AbhiNickz: Please don't remove tags from questions without finding out why they are there.

Comment: @Borodin Because, among other things, my question regards a Perl script.

Comment: Okay, but if we don't even need to see that Perl script, does the tag need to be there? Do you think Perl expertise would help someone to answer your question, or do you think it would help someone searching for help with Perl code? What are the *"other things"*?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `requests`

```
from time import sleep
import requests
with open('c:\dictionary.txt', 'r', 0) as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.strip()
        requests.post("http://www.ca-zeb.com/zebulun/zebulun2/eliza.pl/1903",params={"input":line})
        sleep(2)
```

Comment: Now I get a syntax error for sleep. Just forgot to enclose request.post with ). Thanks for the simple solution!

Comment: @aConvolutedConscious Oops, my bad. See my edited post. Sorry!